# Keras Warning on_batch_begin

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

When training a rnn model using the callback ResetStatesCallback bellow, i get the following warning message:

> /var/venv/DSTL/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:97:
>   UserWarning: Method on_batch_begin() is slow compared to the batch
>   update (0.791834). Check your callbacks.   % delta_t_median)

```python
from keras.callbacks import Callback
#Reset count every RESET_STATES_LENGTH
#RESET_STATES_LENGTH=8
class ResetStatesCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
        if self.counter % RESET_STATES_LENGTH == 0:
            self.model.reset_states()
        self.counter += 1
```

Why do i get this message? Should i try something to fix it? Does it really slow down my training that much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5008 for an explanation. It is stated there that

> You are running something like saving the model or rendering images after each batch and it is taking longer than the batches themselves.

So it would seem that at runtime Keras has determined that your callback is slower than the batch itself.

Comment: I am receiving the same error without any callbacks! any idea why?

Comment: @YehiaElshater Maybe validation?